# specify file type in method parameter

Tags: java, file, parameters, io

I was wondering if it was possible to require a certain type of file in class constructor?

For example:

```
    private class name(File location.txt)
```

I want to have a different constructor for each type of file format that I am going to support.  I could write a method that checks the file and sends it to the appropriate method, but was wondering if it was a possibility to skip that logic?

Comment: Please add a Tag for the language you are using  - consider a Factory: `static TheClass CreateFromExtension(string file)`

Comment: @Alex K. thanks, cant believe I forgot that tag. and I am not exactly a sure what factory is..but it gives me something read up on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this mini factory sample would work for you:

```
public class Test {

    private FileReaderFactory fileReaderFactory = new FileReaderFactory();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileTxt = "test1.txt";
        String filePdf = "test2.pdf";

        Test test = new Test();
        FileTypeI filereaderTxt = test.fileReaderFactory.createFromExtension(fileTxt);
        FileTypeI filereaderPdf = test.fileReaderFactory.createFromExtension(filePdf);

        filereaderTxt.readFile();
        filereaderPdf.readFile();
    }

    public interface FileTypeI {
        void readFile();
    }

    class TextFileReader implements FileTypeI {
        @Override
        public void readFile() {
            //Code to read Text File
        }
    }

    class PDFFileReader implements FileTypeI {
        @Override
        public void readFile() {
            //Code to read PDF File
        }
    }

    class FileReaderFactory {
        public FileTypeI createFromExtension (String filename) {
            FileTypeI returningValue = null;
            if (filename != null && filename.endsWith(".txt")) {
                returningValue = new TextFileReader();
            } 
            else if (filename != null && filename.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                returningValue = new PDFFileReader();
            }
            return returningValue;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the general idea of whats going here. Ill have to read into it but I think you are pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Factory is a Design Pattern. The sample above is one way to implement it.  Here is another [sample](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)
The idea was originally from @alex-k in the comment of your post. ;)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! since you posted an answer I will mark yours as correct and ill upvote alex's comment. thanks for the help guys!